# Link data between neo4j and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-mongodb

I need to create a service that link data between neo4j and mongodb. The service should be a library or a little fast component that serve the data on demand.

Any one knows? how can I do this? I'm evaluating apache camel as an option but maybe there is something most lightly, flexible and fast.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does your mongo data look like?  What does your neo4j data look like?  What kind of connection do you mean?   You need to provide more information before it's going to be possible to help.

Comment: Actually I didn't try anything yet, I'm just designing right now. The idea is to have in mongodb data that doesn't need to be analyzed deeply and in neo4j data that need to be analized deeply and in some cases representation of the relationship between data stored in mongodb. Other reason, is that the data stored in each database needs to separate. I'm going to use Spring Data in the main project construction but I'm not sure if an library developed with spring data would be the best option to server the data linked between mongodb and neo4j.

Comment: What do you mean "link data"? Do you want to have the same set of data in both systems? Do you have to have common id's for query in both systems, but separate data?

Comment: Describe what exactly you are trying to do? Because way of storing data in Mongodb and Neo4j are different. what you mean link data?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [Neo4j Doc Manger](http://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/#_neo4j_doc_manager) project. It works by synching data from MongoDB to Neo4j.